# Is torch.randperm persitence in validation and testing

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, model

I would like to have a question on torch.randperm. I used randperm in my model to reshuffle layers in the torch tensor because ChannelShuffle was not implemented in cuda.

My questions are:

1. Does this function persist in torch.no_grad()? Does torch.randperm generate a new permutation list in validation and testing?
2. Does the torch.randperm generates a new permutation list for each batch in training

This is a block in the model that I am implementing

```
class Fusion_method(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fusion_method,self).__init__()
        
    def mix_func(self, t1, t2, t3, t4):
        input = torch.cat((t1, t2, t3, t4), 1)
        permute = torch.randperm(256, requires_grad=True)
        out = input[:, permute]
        # channel_shuffle = nn.ChannelShuffle(4)
        # out = channel_shuffle(input)
        return out


    def forward(self, t1, t2, t3, t4):
        out = self.mix_func(t1, t2, t3, t4)
        return out
```

Get random permutation each training batch. Remember this permutation as parameter in the model

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

1. `randperm()` is affected by `torch.no_grad()` in the usual manner: no gradient calculation will occur and no memory for gradient tensors will be allocated, even if `require_grad=True` is used. A permutation will be calculated as usual.
2. A new permutation will be calculated as often as you run the model. Assuming you run the model on every batch then yes, a new permutation will be generated for every batch.